# Accessing an API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am writing my first Web Application and for a simple challenge I want to display some Overwatch stats for the user. I was able to accomplish this using NodeJS in some bots that I have made but I cannot use NodeJS now. I know that if I were to have the JSON locally I can access it like so:

```
stats =  {
  name: "This",
  lastName: "That"
}

document.getElementById("overwatchStats").innerHTML = stats.name;
```

but this JSON data is from `https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Calvin-1337/stats`. So I'm not sure how to access it like this (without jquery would be preferred, however if it's not possible/complex I'll use it).

Comment: Most APIs can't be used directly from browsers because of CORS. You need a server proxy.

Comment: It's possible this is what you're looking for https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: Ask the data provider to enable CORS, they often don't even know about CORS and will gladly enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure this would work, but it appears to.  Just grab the data using an XMLHttpRequest and JSON.parse the result to put it into an array.

I've updated it to loop over the objects and output them to the div to just to give an example of how you could do that.

```js
var statsButton = document.getElementById('get-stats');
statsButton.addEventListener('click', function()
  {
    var url = 'https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Calvin-1337/stats';
    GetContent(url);
  }, false);

function GetContent(url, response)
{
    var responseContainer = document.getElementById('response-div');
    
    if (typeof response === 'undefined') {      
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
          //when new content is ready check if animation is still occuring,
          //if it is, add an event listener, otherwise replace content
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
          {
              GetContent(url, xmlhttp.responseText);
          }
      };

      xmlhttp.timeout = 10000;
      
      xmlhttp.ontimeout = function()
      {
          responseContainer.innerHTML = 'Request timed out.';
          xmlhttp.abort();
      };

      xmlhttp.send();
    } else {
        var decodedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
        var content = processResponse(decodedResponse, 0);
        responseContainer.innerHTML = content;
    }
}

function processResponse(response, tab)
{
  var newHTML = '';
  if (typeof response === 'object') {
    for (var property in response) {
      if (response.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        newHTML += '<div>' + addTab(tab) + property + ': ' + 
          processResponse(response[property], + (tab + 1)) + '</div>';
      }
    }
  } else {
    newHTML = response; 
  }

  return newHTML;
}

function addTab(count) {
  var tabs = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    tabs += '&nbsp&nbsp';
  }

  return tabs;
}
```

```html
<div id="response-div">
</div>
<input type="button" value="Get Stats" id="get-stats">
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked well. But how would I access one value? In the last line `console.log(decodedResponse)`, I changed to `decodedResponse.us.stats.competitive.overall_stats.games` and it worked fine, it logged that. But when I tried putting that on the line `responseContainer.innerHTML = response` it didn't like that. I assume I put that in the wrong place.

Comment: You have to access each property one at a time.  I'm not aware of any way to just write the entire object to at once.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something called `XMLHttpRequest`, or just `XHR`.
There is a tutorial on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Basically, here is what you want to do

```
//Define a variable
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
//Add a callback
xhr.onload = function () {
    //The JSON will be stored as a string in the response property of the XHR
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
}
//Open a connection to the API using a GET request
xhr.open("GET", "https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/Calvin-1337/stats");
//Perform the request
xhr.send();
```